# use methd from another scala class

Tags: java, scala, class, abstract-class

I want to define a Point class with distance method and later to define a Triangle class and three methods: def isIsosceles(), def isEscaleno(), def isEquilatero().

I wrote this but it is uncorrect. How I could correct it?

```
class Point(x:Double, y:Double){
  var _0:Double = x
  var _1:Double = y



def distance(other:Point):Double = scala.math.sqrt(scala.math.pow((_0 - other._0),2) + scala.math.pow((_1 - other._1),2))
}

class Triangle(p1:Point,p2:Point,p3:Point){
  var _1:Point = p1
  var _2:Point = p2
  var _3:Point = p3



   def longSides():ListBuffer[Double]={
      var list:ListBuffer[Double] = ListBuffer[Double]()
      val p1:Point = _1
      val p2:Point = _2
      val p3:Point = _3
      list += p1.distance(p2)
      list += p2.distance(p3)
      list += p3.distance(p1)
      list
  }

  def isIsosceles():Boolean = longSides.distinct.length == 2
  def isEscaleno():Boolean = longSides.distinct.length == 3
  def isEquilatero():Boolean = longSides.distinct.length == 1
}
```

Comment: No need to use so many mutability for this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/T8OTdGZYSOSfbe8dtVSXYg/1

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank yyou very much. One question: why do you write case in these line ?: sides.map {
        case (p1, p2) =>
          ((p1 -> p2), p1.distance(p2))
      }

Comment: Because `sides` is a `Set` of tuples, thus if I want to extract the individual elements I need to pattern match it. That is **Scala** 101. I would recommend you to pick a proper learning material and to join the [**discord** server](https://discord.gg/J5dfteJJ) which is more suited for this kind of questions.